# Get custom post types posts using custom meta fileds value wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, meta-boxes

```
$posts = new WP_Query( [
        'post_type'  => 'mock_test',
        'meta_query' => array(
        'key'     => 'selectedchapter',
        'value' => 15
        ),
    ] );

 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($posts);
 echo "</pre>";
```

I need to get posts which have selected chapter 2 in custom meta box. This WP_Query not working for me, I'm getting all the posts.
see attached screenshot (https://prnt.sc/vuzw6lhW44mR) of metabox html structure.

Comment: It seems something is wrong with your meta_query. What is 15 in the value here? Also, Can you let me know what is selectechapter here, is it a taxonomy?

Comment: @SurajSanwal Yes selectedchapter are taxonomy of another post type (subject). I've called them in posttype mock_test as checkboxes.
And 15 is id of taxonomy chapter 2. 
I just need posts (mock_test) which have chapter 2 selected in custom meta box.

Comment: Okay. So you need to use tax_query instead meta_query, tax_query let you query using a custom taxonomy.

Comment: @SurajSanwal These are not taxonomy here since they are called here as custom fields. please see this screenshot (https://prnt.sc/ScIhpzOGjXKU) I've explained in it.

Comment: Be sure your integration first. Is there are taxonomy or custom fields. If this is a custom field then pass the value of the field instead id in your meta_query

Comment: @SurajSanwal These are Taxonomy(chapters) of another post type not from this (mock_test) post type . But I've created custom meta box inside (mock_test) and then called the chapters (which are taxonomy) inside the custom meta box.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple way to get post where the custom field key is 'color' and the custom field value is ‘blue’:

```
   $args = array(
       'post_type' => 'product',
        'meta_key' => 'color',
       'meta_value' => 'blue'
     );
    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these code

```
$args = array(  
        'post_type' => 'mock_test', 
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 
        
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 

        print the_title(); 
        the_excerpt(); 
        $meta_print_value=get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'selectedchapter',true);
        echo $meta_print_value;

    endwhile;
```